# CSS crossfade background-images working, but causing div on top to of background to disappear

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have been working on a way to do this for an entire day, and finally got a working slideshow going on for my background-images.

It is currently 100% css/html, with fade in and out between images.

Only problem is my login form above the background now keeps disappearing with the fade in and out of the images.

I need the login form to ALWAYS Be there.  Help.

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/img/favicon.png">

    <title>Login Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->    
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->
    <link href="/Content/css/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

  <body id="background">
      <ul class="cb-slideshow">
          <li><span>BG-1</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-2</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-3</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-4</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-5</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-6</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-7</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-8</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-9</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-10</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-11</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-12</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-13</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-14</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-15</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-16</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-17</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-18</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-19</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-20</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-21</span></li>
          <li><span>BG-22</span></li>
      </ul>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="login-form" action="index.html">        
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="white">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    <span class="pull-right"> <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Signup</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my slideshow.css

```
.cb-slideshow, 
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    /*background: transparent url(../Content/img/BackGround/pattern.png) repeat top left;*/
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 660s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 60s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 90s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-5.jpg);
    animation-delay: 120s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-6.jpg);
    animation-delay: 150s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(7) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-7.jpg);
    animation-delay: 180s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(8) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-8.jpg);
    animation-delay: 210s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(9) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-9.jpg);
    animation-delay: 240s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(10) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-10.jpg);
    animation-delay: 270s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(11) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-11.jpg);
    animation-delay: 300s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(12) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-12.jpg);
    animation-delay: 330s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(13) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-13.jpg);
    animation-delay: 360s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(14) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-14.jpg);
    animation-delay: 390s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(15) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-15.jpg);
    animation-delay: 420s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(16) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-16.jpg);
    animation-delay: 450s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(17) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-17.jpg);
    animation-delay: 480s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(18) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-18.jpg);
    animation-delay: 510s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(19) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-19.jpg);
    animation-delay: 540s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(20) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-20.jpg);
    animation-delay: 570s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(21) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-21.jpg);
    animation-delay: 600s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(22) span { 
    background-image: url(../Content/img/BackGround/BG-22.jpg);
    animation-delay: 630s; 
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    2.25% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    4.5% { opacity: 1 }
    6.75% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Comment: If you add `position:relative;` to your `.container` or `.login-form` that should fix it. If I understand your issue correctly, you're setting the slideshow to be a higher order in the DOM tree. Even though you set the `z-index` to 0 for the slideshow, it's still going to remain on top with the `position:fixed` declaration. If adding `position:relative` doesn't fix it, keep it and add `z-index:1` to the attribute.

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/5j6p8nmq/)

Comment: I thought it was opacity that was causing the elements to fade in and out as the images cycled through.

Comment: I don't think so Tiny as your fiddle shows the login now below the background in the page.  I want a single page here with the login right in the center of the page never fading with the background-images changing underneath the login form.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle of your original code so we can fiddle with it